# move softwares without changing path

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, path

I bought a new laptop with only 512gb of storage so i installed all my softwares on an external 4tb hard drive. but as you might imagine, it's not very practical because i always need to cary my PC and my external drive. that's why i just ordered an internal SSD. so my question is, if i copy my external drive to the new SSD and change it's letter to be the same as the HDD before so that the path to my softwares stay the sames, but they aren't  on the same drive anymore, would they still work ?
if not, do you have any idea on how to transfer my softwares without reinstalling everything ?

Comment: Your going to need to just reinstall the software.  If software uses the registry to store and manage the path to it's application directory is entirely up to the programmer.  Some applications are perfectly fine with just being ran in a new location others will not even work.

Comment: yes i know that there is some softwares that can be moved, but my question was more about the others, because as you said, their paths are stored on the registery but the whole point of changing the new drive letter was to keep the same path even if the physical drive changed.

Comment: If the drive letter and thus the path of the used files and folders stays the same nearly all  programs should just continue to work. Just make sure you don't forget to copy some files because they are hidden in Explorer or something like that. I would recommend to use a command-line tool like `robocopy.exe` (included in Windows 10) to copy the files and folders.

Comment: Its far easier to uninstall the old software, install it again, and then copy the data from the external drive to the new path overwriting all files. Guaranteed that it will work, and no need to do anything to keep the drive letters the same.

Comment: Can you not play around with links from the original directory to the new path?

Comment: Although what you ask is *possible*, it isn't *practical*.  You will spend far too much time making this work to be worth it.. risking the partitions (and therefore your data) on the SSD drive in the process.  What I mean.. 1) shrink 'c:' 2) add new partition to the drive 3) remap drive letters to match what you want after making sure no open handles on external drive. 4) `robocopy` the contents from external to SSD new partition. 5) ***hope*** you didn't screw anything up.  This is a bad plan.